# MySQL - Day, Month, Unspecified Year

Tags: mysql, date

I'm working with 4 tables as following:

hotels(hotel_num, hotel_name, city)

rooms(room_num, hotel_num, room_type, price)

bookings(hotel_num, guest_num, arr_date, dep_date, room_num)

guests(guest_num, guest_name, guest_address)

I have to find bookings where someone will be staying at a particular hotel on New Year's Day but of a non specific year.

I have tried:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM hotels AS h
JOIN rooms AS r
JOIN bookings AS b
ON h.hotel_num = r.hotel_num  
AND b.hotel_num = h.hotel_num
AND b.room_num = r.room_num
WHERE h.hotel_name = 'Hotel California' 
AND 01 BETWEEN MONTH(b.arr_date) AND MONTH(b.dep_date) 
AND 01 BETWEEN DAY(b.arr_date) AND DAY(b.dep_date)
GROUP BY b.hotel_num);
```

I imagine this approach isn't working from the point of view that a booking can start on Christmas Day and end in February but the month goes from 12 to 2 which 1 is not between.

Is there a way to specify a month and day without a year?

Edit: Results should be a number, ie 7, which tells you how many rooms are booked on 01/01/xxxx

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this condition will select the bookings on "New Years Day":

```
where year(arr_date)<>year(dep_date)
```

Unless someone arriving on "New Years "day" and departing on the same day should also be selected, but that is not very hard to add, is it?